# Import vertices from .OBJ and then convert all to dynamically linked objects

Tags: import, linked-data

I am generating a large network of vertices and edges in another app and exporting them into a Wavefront (*.obj) file for import into Blender. All the vertices are in a group, say "nodes".

Is there a way to, after importing the .obj and selecting all the vertices in the "nodes" group, to dynamically link them to an object in another Blender file?

There are hundreds of these vertices and so adding objects at all their locations isn't feasible.

If working with plain unconnected vertices is a problem, I can replaces them with small cubes or something.  The point is to later convert them into dynamically linked objects to anything else of my choice.

NOTE: The main point is to just save time and resources when dealing with 1000's of duplicated objects that I may need to modify later.  So, the answer doesn't have to fit the question 100%, e.g., the dynamically linked part is optional.

Thank you,
Al

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Blender's [dupliverts](http://www.blender.org/manual/modeling/objects/duplication/dupliverts.html) feature can duplicate an object at every vertex of an object.

Parent the object to the vertices only object by selecting the object you want duplicated then shift select the object that has only vertices and parent them by pressing <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>P</kbd> and selecting object. Then in the Object properties under Duplication enable Verts.

[image]

Comment: Works great!  I discovered that having 1000's of links requires the creating of 1000's of individual objects which brings Blender to a crawl forever.  But, this doesn't list 1000's of the duplicates in the object viewer and there is no delay.